Spark can not create the managed table with overwrite mode
Question
There are other questions on this topic (see here, here, and here), but I haven't seen any address this question head on:
In Spark > 3.0.0, why does it seem that the "overwrite" mode sometimes doesn't work, and what is the best method to solve?
Problem
When writing out a snapshot table that gets overwritten every day, this code executes:
my_dataframe.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('my_database.my_table')

In some deployments this has worked. However, sometimes the following error occurs:
AnalysisException: Can not create the managed table('`my_database`.`my_table`'). The associated location('s3://my_bucket/my_database.db/my_table') already exists.

Context
Databricks is not being used, so any strategies would have to just use PySpark.
